# Can't interact with views and their events inside OnClick\OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, imagebutton

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

//all the imports

public class VocabularyManager extends Application{
    ProgressBar progress;
    ImageButton volup;
    ImageButton voldown;
    TextView current_vol_text;
    //[Cut-out Definitions of Variables]
    ImageButton.OnClickListener changevol;
    public VocabularyManager(Activity activity, Context context, String Category) {
        //Don't wonder, many things up here are also cut-out
        dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_dialog, null);
        volup = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.vol_up); //MARKER #1
        voldown = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.vol_down); //MARKER #2
        progress = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.progress); //MARKER #3
        list = (ListView) this.act.findViewById(R.id.vocabulary_list);

        listadapter = new WordAdapter(this.act, mwords);

        list.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.category_family));

        list.setAdapter(listadapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                list.setEnabled(false);
                Word word = mwords.get(i);
                timer = new Timer();
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_dialog, null);
                volup.setOnClickListener(changevol);
                voldown.setOnClickListener(changevol);
                progress = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                current_vol_text = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.current_stream_volume);
                current_vol_text.setText(Integer.toString(mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)));
                //Setting up the 'dialog' AlertDialog.Builder
                crdialog = dialog.create();
                int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
                if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    if(mMediaPlayer == null) {
                        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, word.getAudio());
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                    }
                }
                progress.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
                progress.setProgress(0);
                crdialog.show();
                ttask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(mMediaPlayer != null) {
                            progress.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(ttask, 0, 50);
            }
        });
        changevol = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(view.getId() == R.id.vol_up){
                    mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,0);
                }
                else{
                    mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,0);
                }
                current_vol_text.setText(Integer.toString(mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The probem with this code is:I am trying to change the `STREAM_MUSIC` Volume inside an OnClickListener(`volchange`) for the two buttons `volup` and `voldown`.  For some reason, the OnClickListener is not firing, but if i open the logcat, no errors, warnings or suspicious logs are shown. What causes this behaviour?

> As in the comments mentioned, the unnecessary parts of the code are
>   cut-out for this post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the rest of the `AlertDialog` code.

Comment: +Mike M i have already got the bug fix, i am soon going to add the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, **initialize the `volup`/`voldown`  - ImageButtons in the OnItemClickListener, after `dialogview` is inflated.**
Although the widgets are initialized in the class constructor, this step needs to be done.
The same procedure should be done to every other view/widget, which is able to update on the UIThread by calling the relevant method.

### Why this behaviour?

Theoretically we correctly initialize the views and widgets after inflating the `dialogview` in the class constructor.
But when we inflate the `dialogview` in the constructor (before initializing the OnItemClickListener), the layout itself gets inflated, *directly* after calling the constructor, and from that 'binary' inflated Layout, then we get the views.  *But here comes the problem:* Everytime the OnItemClickListener is triggered, a new binary Layout gets inflated and saved into `dialogview`. So now the Layout applied to the `dialog` is a new created binary Layout from the `dialogview`-Variable, **but** the `volup` & `voldown` ImageButtons still refer to the binary Layout that was created earlier, when we once called the class constructor. *So obviously, if we initialize the ImageButtons every time after the `dialogview` is created, the buttons refer to the correct, new inflated Layout.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the final keyword for image button local declarations

Comment: Removing the final keyword didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the "final" from ImageButton.

Comment: Removing the final keyword didn't change the behavior.